# How to convert RAvg type data to float properly in Python?

Tags: python, types

I am using a integral method [vegas](https://github.com/gplepage/vegas) in Python, below is a minimal example

```py
import vegas

sigma = lambda x: 1e-7 * x

integrator = vegas.Integrator([[0.0, 1.0]])
cross_section = integrator(sigma, nitn = 10, neval = 10000)
print cross_section
print type(cross_section)
```

which will print

```sh
[5.0000113(83)e-08]
<class 'vegas._vegas.RAvgArray'>
```

The type of the data is unheard to me and I certainly want to convert it to a `float` type data, I know I could do it by hand

```py
float(str(cross_section[0]).split('(')[0] + str(cross_section[0]).split(')')[1])
```

But this does not seem clever to me, is there a neat way of manipulating such data?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [vegas source code](https://github.com/gplepage/vegas/blob/master/src/vegas/_vegas.pyx#L1733),

> [RAvgArray] elements are `gvar.GVar`s (from the `gvar` module if present) and represent Gaussian random variables.

`gvar.GVar` objects in turn, according to [their documentation](https://gvar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gvar.html#gvar-gvar-objects), have attributes `mean`, `sdev` and `var`.

It looks like you want this:

```
cross_section[0].mean
```